# Facebook iOS SDK 3.5 Mobile Safari login not working

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication, sdk, safari

I recently updated my Facebook SDK to the newest version (3.5.2). My app will log into facebook if I have either:

1) Facebook logged in through Settings for iOS 6

2) Facebook app installed on my device

But for some reason, if I have neither, the app will switch to Safari to log in and when it returns back to my app, I am still logged out. Any ideas?

At first I thought it might be the app-switching, but switching to the Facebook App to log in works.

I have already implemented the new FBAppCall for openURL and added [FBAppCall handleDidBecomeActive];

Thanks in advance!